# MongoDB return specific value in top of list

Tags: mongodb, sorting

My sorting should be by Country such that - **"India"** is always on the top, rest alphabetically sorted.

How can I achieve that with a **mongo-shell command**?

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a797000287389c34c70c525"),
        "Country" : "World",
        "Population" : "7550262101"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a797000287389c34c70c526"),
        "Country" : "China",
        "Population" : 1409517397
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a797000287389c34c70c527"),
        "Country" : "India",
        "Population" : 1339180127
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a797000287389c34c70c528"),
        "Country" : "USA",
        "Population" : 324459463
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a797000287389c34c70c529"),
        "Country" : "Indonesia",
        "Population" : 263991379
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After referring to another post on [Dynamic Sticky Sorting in Mongo for a simple value or list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749236/dynamic-sticky-sorting-in-mongo-for-a-simple-value-or-list) I figured out a way to achieve the desired result is

```
db.population.aggregate(
[
  {$project: {
    Country: 1,
    Population: 1,
    sticky: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$Country', 'India']}, 1, 0]}
  }},
  {$sort: 
    {sticky: -1,
    Country: 1}
  },
  {$project: {
    Country: 1,
    Population: 1,
  }}
])
```

The result of the above query is

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a797000287389c34c70c527"), "Country" : "India", "Population" : 1339180127 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a797000287389c34c70c525"), "Country" : "World", "Population" : "7550262101" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a797000287389c34c70c526"), "Country" : "China", "Population" : 1409517397 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a797000287389c34c70c528"), "Country" : "USA", "Population" : 324459463 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a797000287389c34c70c529"), "Country" : "Indonesia", "Population" : 263991379 }
```

Comment: You said you wanted the rest of the fields alphabetically sorted? Also, you might want to edit the question to put this in instead of an answer